# PHP Contact Form Assistance

Tags: php, html, contacts

I'm sort of a noob when it comes to HTML and PHP. Anyways, I made a html form and then I got a PHP mail script from online and edited the PHP code so that it matched with my HTML. The form actually works and it sends me the email. Problem is that some of the stuff from the form that was filled in, comes up empty on the email that is sent to me. On the code below you can see that the form that I have are:

- Name
- Address
- Phone
- Email
- Residence (3 Radio buttons with three different options)
- Applicable text field

When the WHOLE form is filled and submitted, when I get the email, all I get is the Name and Phone.

Heres the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>SpaceCommand - Order Now</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://cdn.directv.com/images/common/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ostyle.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="top"></div>
<div id="st"><img src="dimages/nflst.png" width="1021" height="550"/></div>
<div id="Every">Every Sunday. Every Game.</div>
<div id="tbox"></div>
<div id="tbox_2"></div>

<div id="Every_2">NFL SUNDAY TICKET included</div>
<div id="Every_3">at no extra charge!</div>
<div id="Every_4">Only on DIRECTV.</div>

<div id="logo"><img src="dimages/logof.png" width="400" height="51" /></div>



<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="form1" action="mail.php" method="POST">

    <label>Name
        <span class="small">Add your name</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">


    <label>Address
        <span class="small">Enter your address</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="address">


    <label>Phone
        <span class="small">Add a Phone Number</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone">


    <label>Email
        <span class="small">Enter your email</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
 <br />



<label>Residence:
</label>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="radio">
    House<input type="radio" value="house" name="house">
</div>

<div id="radio2">
    Condo<input type="radio" value="condo" name="condo">
</div>

<div id="radio3">
    Apartment<input type="radio" value="apartment" name="apartment">
</div>
<br />
<br/>
    <label>If apartment or condo, do you have roof availability or a balcony facing south?
        <span class="small"><i>*if applicable</i></span>
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="applicable">

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

    <button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;">Submit</button>
    <div class="spacer"></div>

</div>
</form>

<div id="ont">
<img src="dpimages/ont.png" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//Cusomer Name
$name = $_POST['name'];
//Address
$address = $_POST['address'];
//Phone
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
//Email
$email = $_POST['email'];
//Residence
$residence = $_POST['residence'];
//Residence Type
$house = $_POST['house'];
$condo = $_POST['condo'];
$apartment = $_POST['apartment'];
//Applicable 
$applicable = $_POST['applicable'];

//Contetnt
$formcontent= "Customer Name: $name \n Address: $address \n Phone Number: $phone \n Email: $email \n Residence: $residence $house $condo $apartment \n Do they have roof access or a baclony facing south? (if applicable): $applicable";
$recipient = "gizmo@themvnt.com";
$subject = "DIRECTV Order - SpaceCommand";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You for contacting us. We'll get back to you as soon as possible." . " -" . "<a href='order.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return to SpaceCommand</a>";
?>
```

If you guys can fix the code for me, that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: `var_dump($_POST)` results.

```
Array ( [name] => Test Name 
[Address] => Test Address 
[phone] => Tes Phome 
[Email] => Test Email 
[call] => House 
[Applicable] => 
Test ) Thank You for contacting us. We'll get back to you as soon as possible. - Return to SpaceCommand
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong the code... Have you tried outputting the variables on the page, so you can see if they're actually taking?

Comment: print_r($_POST); before the mail sending, see if that's correctly populated.

Comment: @zenkaty Im guessing that you're saying if I tried filling in the form myself? If so, yes.

Comment: They are saying at the top of your php script put `print_r($_POST);`. This will print out all values of the `$_POST` array and make sure they are being sent properly

Comment: This is what I got:                                               Array ( [name] => Test Name [Address] => Test Address [phone] => Tes Phome [Email] => Test Email [call] => House [Applicable] => Test ) Thank You for contacting us. We'll get back to you as soon as possible. - Return to SpaceCommand

Comment: that does not match the code above, look at the key case

Comment: Are you sure the HTML you posted is the HTML you're using? `[Email]` is not what is in your form. You have `email`

Comment: Indeed, the problem here is that you are trying to use lowercase $_POST vars, while some vars are capitalized. Fix this in your html source (make all input names lowercase)

Comment: SUCCESS! I just forgot to update my cPanel HTML file. Please excuse my ignorance. Thank you all for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

your radio buttons should have the three of them the same name, unless you want to allow them to choose the three at the same time.

Also try this

```
$formcontent= "Customer Name: {$name} \n Address: {$address} \n Phone Number: {$phone} \n Email: {$email} \n Residence: {$residence} $house {$condo} {$apartment} \n Do they have roof access or a baclony facing south? (if applicable): {$applicable}";
```

I tested the form and all the values are being passed right.

Comment: So I should be getting all the information via email? I tried all the suggestions that you guys have given me and Im still just getting the name and phone number of the customer.

Comment: try echo $formcontent; over $recipient = "gizmo@themvnt.com"; to see what it gives you

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. How do you put the three radio buttons as the same name?

Comment: where it says name="house" , name="condo", name="apartment", replace with name="residence" in the three of them but leave the value as is. and from the form you can erase $house = $_POST['house'];
$condo = $_POST['condo'];
$apartment = $_POST['apartment']; and erase  $house $condo $apartment from the $formcontent variable

Comment: Thanks bro. I'd give you rep (which you deserve) but I dont have the required rep.

Answer (score -1):

The capitalization is different in the $_POST keys than it is in your code.

I.e. in the post it shows up as Email, but you are accessing it as $_POST['email'] instead of $_POST['Email']

This however doesn't match the html code that you posted in your original question however.  Are you sure the html code in your question is the same as what you are running?

[Update that didn't print well in the comment:]
Based on the results of what you printed your php code should look like:

```
//Cusomer Name
$name = $_POST['name'];
//Address
$address = $_POST['Address'];
//Phone
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
//Email
$email = $_POST['Email'];
//Applicable 
$applicable = $_POST['Applicable'];
```

Comment: You could at least try and make this an original answer instead of reading the comments above and rehashing a solved problem.

Comment: Check the times on the responses.  There was nothing posted about the capitalization being an issue at the time that I posted my answer.